# Configure Azure WebApp with ACR and Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry, azure-managed-identity

Considering that both Azure WebApp and Azure Container Registry support Managed Identities, is there a way to configure the WebApp in order to pull a docker image from ACR directly (Without keyvault)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, the Managed Identity for the Web App is used inside the containers to access other resources. It means the web app needs to run well and you can access other resources through the code with Managed Identity.

And also as I know, the authentication to pull the images in ACR, you only can use the environment variables of the Web App, take a look at the [description](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#ACRSettings).